# Is there a way to ask for autoplay programmaticaly for firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, autoplay

Is there a way to ask for autoplay permission in firefox using javascript ? Autoplay can be activated manually, but what I want is to ask for permission programmatically.
(For example, when I want to use webcam, it asks to the user if webcam can be used, I want to know if there is a way to do like this, but for video/audio autoplay)

```
<audio autoplay>
   <source src="path/to/the/audio/file.mp3">
</audio>
```

I expect the sound plays automatically, but I get the following error:

`NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<audio id='audio'>
    <source src="path/to/the/audio/file.mp3">
</audio>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#audio').autoplay = true;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). But this does not work :( This results the same result as I done before. The thing is, sometimes the browser does not allow the sound/video to play automatically. It can be changed manually, but the thing I want to show a popup, so that user can activate it easily